# Why does a hudson "mvn clean install" build take 3-6x longer than the same on the command line?

Tags: performance, maven-2, hudson, nexus, jenkins

We are seeing relatively long build times on our CI server (hudson) and they're starting to get in our way. I am aware hudson does more than invoke maven and I would happily grant it 10-20% more time for the job, but an order of magnitude slowdown seems too much.

Anyone have an idea of why this might be and how to solve the problem? I will start by saying what is *not* the cause:

- the virtual machine hudson is running in: on the command line, it takes roughly the same amount of time as my development PC
- other concurrent tasks: I made sure there was nothing diverting resources from the build task

The maven goals are literally clean and install, nothing fancy and resource-intensive like javadoc, checkstyle etc. Looking at the hudson build task console output, there seem to be delays when "Retrieving previous build number from [our Nexus artefact repository]", but I don't know of a simple way to measure performance of this step and publishing an artefact seems too simple an operation to justify the total difference in speed.

(problem also described in [this](http://hudson.361315.n4.nabble.com/Hudson-Maven2-slow-execution-td3015735.html) thread)

**Update:**

We have upgraded Hudson/Jenkins to the latest release and have been able to use the timing plugin. Short version:

- the good news: we now know **nexus is causing the problem**
- the bad news: we still don't know why

More details

On one of our actual maven projects (maven build time: 3 min, hudson build time: 9 min) we could see that hudson also performs the build in 3 min, but then takes 6 minutes to upload the artefact to nexus.

Performing a manual upload of another artefact using nexus' web UI, I was able to confirm the following:

- the actual artefact upload is done in a fraction of the time (i.e., in several seconds)
- after these several seconds, the artefact appears as `<nexusworkdir>/nexus/storage/test/test2/test2/1.0.0/test2-1.0.0.rpm`

**The real puzzler** is why nexus takes over a minute to create this file:
`<nexusworkdir>/nexus/proxy/attributes/test/test2/test2/1.0.0/test2-1.0.0.rpm`

As far as I can tell, it just calculates an MD5 and SHA1 signature and records general artefact information, but md5sum and sha1sum of a 75MB file take <1s to run...

Finally, it does not appear to be some sort of network time-out, because the delay seems to be roughly proportional to artefact size.

Any idea what nexus does after it receives an artefact is appreciated.

**Update 2**:

Setting the nexus log level to debug, nexus logs the following when an artefact is uploaded:

> ```
> ...
>
> 2011-04-05 14:38:53 DEBUG [jpsc28za2RtYQ==] -
> ```
>
> o.s.n.p.s.l.f.Defau~          -
>   Copying stream with buffer size of:
>   4096
>
> ```
> 2011-04-05 14:39:55 DEBUG [ython-2.5.2.jar] - org.mortbay.log
> ```
>
> - RESPONSE /nexus/content/groups/public/org/python/jython/2.5.2/jython-2.5.2.jar
>   200
>
> ```
> 2011-04-05 14:40:07 DEBUG [-2.5.2.jar.sha1] - org.mortbay.log
> ```
>
> - REQUEST /nexus/content/groups/public/org/python/jython/2.5.2/jython-2.5.2.jar.sha1
>   on
>
> ```
> ...
>
> 2011-04-05 14:40:12 DEBUG [-2.5.2.jar.sha1] - org.mortbay.log
> ```
>
> - RESPONSE /nexus/content/groups/public/org/python/jython/2.5.2/jython-2.5.2.jar.sha1
>   200
>
> ```
> 2011-04-05 14:43:45 DEBUG [ndex.properties] - org.mortbay.log
> ```
>
> - REQUEST /nexus/content/groups/public/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
>   on
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection@141a720
>
> ```
> ...
>
> 2011-04-05 14:44:04 DEBUG [ndex.properties] -
> ```
>
> o.s.n.p.m.m.M2Group~          - public
>   retrieveItem() :: FOUND
>   public:/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
>
> ```
> 2011-04-05 14:44:04 DEBUG [ndex.properties] - org.mortbay.log
> ```
>
> - RESPONSE /nexus/content/groups/public/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
>   200
>
> ```
> 2011-04-05 14:48:07 DEBUG [jpsc28za2RtYQ==] -
> ```
>
> o.s.n.p.a.DefaultAt~          -
>   Storing attributes on
>   UID=test:/test/test/1.0.1/test-1.0.1.rpm
>
> ```
> ...
>
> 2011-04-05 14:48:07 DEBUG [w/icon-info.gif] - org.mortbay.log
> ```
>
> - servlet holder=nexus
>
> ```
> 2011-04-05 14:48:08 DEBUG [w/icon-info.gif] - org.mortbay.log
> ```
>
> - RESPONSE /nexus/ext-2.3/resources/images/default/window/icon-info.gif
>   200
>
> ```
> 2011-04-05 14:49:01 DEBUG [c=1302007326656] - org.mortbay.log
> ```
>
> - REQUEST /nexus/service/local/log/config on
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection@1dbd88f
>       ....

It appears to just be sitting there for a minute or so and than continues with its work. Any idea why nexus does this is appreciated.

Comment: check whether hudson actually uses Java 1.6 to compile instead of java 1.5. That makes a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Peter, but Java 1.5 is not installed on the machine: we're using OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode).

Comment: Did you included the time to check out the code from the scm to the Hudson build times? If not, compare the output for the manual and Hudson build to find out the difference. It might be just different java settings. (increase the level of verbosity for both)

Comment: I didn't think the code checkout would matter much: I just tried it out and it took about 5s to complete, which leaves a lot to be explained still. I'll try getting more information using the "timestamper" hudson plugin, but I'll have to upgrade hudson to do it...

Comment: Maven does provide timestamps on it's process so you should be able to see where it is hanging (if it is only only step causing the problem). Also, check which version of maven Hudson is using. You might be using Maven 3 on the command line and on your dev box but Hudson is configured to use Maven 2. Maven 3 is at least twice as fast as 2 which might explain it.

Comment: For some reason I didn't see your reply earlier, sorry. We're not running Maven 3 so it's not that. Timestamps are obviously something I hope to use, but as I said, I need to upgrade hudson first. Still, thanks for the sensible suggestions.

Comment: We have seen the same issue, but not with Maven. Simple cmake/makefile builds for us take a lot longer on Hudson than on command line. I attributed the issue to the flow of data show on the console (build console -> hudson client -> hudson master -> hudson console).

Comment: do you need to install? can you just verify?

Comment: @dustyprogrammer: I'm not sure I follow... You suggest calling mvn verify instead of mvn install? What would be the point?

Comment: its just a hunch, can you try it and see if you still see the same slow down.

Comment: Are you running any other instrumentation on your builds like cobertura? It's a long known issue that this causes tests to run multiple times, hence increase build times.

Comment: Thanks for the idea puug, but the delay appears to be concentrated around nexus artefact deployment. When I understand what goes on during deployment, I expect I'll be able to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the thread I suspect your forked Maven isn't getting the JVM parameters passed. Can you use jconsole to check the max heap allowed is what you have allocated in your MAVEN_OPTS?

Does it make any difference if you start Hudson as a service vs. starting Hudson from the command line?

**Update**:

Deploying on Nexus takes a load of RAM, much more than compiling (in my experience). The swapping on low memory might be what's slowing it down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think that explains why Jenkins builds the binary almost as fast as Maven, but then takes a long time to deploy it.

Comment: Deploying takes a load of RAM, much more than compiling (in my experience). The swapping on low memory might be what's slowing it down.

Comment: That might be something to look into, but than it's not Maven's JVM settings I should tweak, but Nexus'. I'll see if I can find some time to give it a try...

Comment: That was it, it appears: when we increased the amount of memory available to the Xen VM running Nexus, deployment time became negligible. I might do a few more tests to confirm, but unless they show something unexpected, I consider this one resolved...

Comment: So your basic problem was that the underlying platform had too little memory and started swapping.  Did you check this as part of initial investigation or were you simply focussing on JVM performance?